# Covering SELECT on index gives using where; using index; instead of only using index;

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, innodb, b-tree

**Query:**

```
SELECT A from table_name where A = 'a';
```

**Explain Output**

```
1   SIMPLE  table_name  ref A_idx   A_idx   1   const   40582635    **Using where; Using index**
```

**Question**

I have a composite index `A_idx on (A,B,C)...`

I am expecting the output to be only *using index* since the index covers the complete query. But I still get a *using where; using index*...

The column in question is an ENUM with the following definition.

```
A enum('a','b','c') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
```

Comment: apparantly im even getting this.. if i do `select id from table where id > 100`  ....

Comment: Let's check things a diff way.  What do you get from `FLUSH STATUS; SELECT ... ; SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`  And how many rows in the table?

Comment: I"ll do that and share the results soon

Comment: File a bug at http://bugs.mysql.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the corresponding section of [explain output documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information), "even if you are using an index for all parts of a WHERE clause, you may see Using where if the column can be NULL."

Update: The documentation also says that "if the Extra column also says Using where [besides using index], it means the index is being used to perform lookups of key values."

Comment: the column is not null.. hence i added the column definition.

Comment: It should not be looking up key values, since the values required are part of the index itself right.. isn't that the whole point of covering indices. ?

Comment: Apparently the optimizer decided against that.

Comment: even for `select count(*) from table where id > 100`